# is there a way to implement pandas wide_to_long in Polars?

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I use Pandas wide to long to stack survey data and it works beautifully with regex and stub names, is this possible to do in Polars ?

e.g. in Pandas -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'famid': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
'birth': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
'ht_one': [2.8, 2.9, 2.2, 2, 1.8, 1.9, 2.2, 2.3, 2.1],
'ht_two': [3.4, 3.8, 2.9, 3.2, 2.8, 2.4, 3.3, 3.4, 2.9]
})
changed_df = pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                              stubnames='ht', 
                              i=['famid', 'birth'], 
                              j='age',
                              sep='_', 
                              suffix=r'\w+')
```

stubnames can take a list as well.

Edit- Added code after taking inspiration from Jqurious -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
import re

# Create age group data
age_groups = np.random.choice(['0-18', '19-35', '36-50', '51-65', '65+'], size=10)

# Create gender data
genders = np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female', 'Other'], size=10)

# Create familiarity and affinity data
fam_aff = np.random.rand(10, 4)

# Create column names
cols = ['Age_group', 'Gender', 'Familiarity_loop1', 'Familiarity_loop2', 'Affinity_loop1', 'Affinity_loop2']

# Combine data into dataframe
data = np.column_stack([age_groups, genders, fam_aff])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)
df["unique_records"] = np.arange(len(df))

regex_pattern = '^.*_loop\d'

# get polars DF
pl_df = pl.from_pandas(df)

# get all columns list
col_list = pl_df.columns

loop_list = [] # list of columns which contains _loop
sans_loop_list = [] # list of columns which do not contain _loop

for col in col_list:
    if re.search(regex_pattern, col):
        loop_list.append(col)
    else:
        sans_loop_list.append(col)
        

pl_melt_df = (pl_df
 .melt(
    id_vars = pl_df.select(sans_loop_list).columns, 
    variable_name = "master_stack")
    .with_columns(pl.col("master_stack").str.replace(r"_loop\d","")) 
)

pl_melt_df.pivot(index=sans_loop_list, columns="master_stack", values="value")
```

I want to see Affinity and Familiarity as their own columns, but I am not able to achieve it.

Edit 2 - Added Polars output and Pandas output

Polars -
[image: polars melt and pivot output]

Pandas output -
[image: pandas wide_to_long output]

Comment: After `pdf_melt_df.pivot` I see `Affinity` and `Familiarity` as their own columns, so it's not entirely clear what output you want. Can you show the `pd.wide_to_long` you would use for this new example? And/or the expected output?

Comment: Hey @jqurious I have attached outputs from both Polars and Pandas, the problem with Polars pivot is that I am losing data, while in wide_to_long the data is maintained.

Comment: That's because of the `.pivot` - you'd need a count of each "group" to use in the pivot index e.g. `.melt().with_columns(index = pl.arange(0, pl.count()).over("variable"))` - then use `.pivot(index = sans_loop_list + ["index"], ...)`

Comment: I tried

``` pl_melt_df = (pl_df
 .melt(
    id_vars = pl_df.select(sans_loop_list).columns, 
    variable_name = "master_stack")
    .with_columns(index = pl.arange(0, pl.count()).over("master_stack"))
    .with_columns(pl.col("master_stack").str.replace(r"_loop\d","")) 
)

# pl_melt_df
p_m_d = pl_melt_df.pivot(index=sans_loop_list + ["index"], columns="master_stack", values="value")

p_m_d
``` but it still shows 10 rows

Comment: I've added an example to my answer, does that generate the output you're after? If not, can you add the `pd.wide_to_long` code you're using to generate the pandas output image?

Comment: Okay yes, it needs to be done after the `.replace()`. It's only when you remove the suffix from the variable column that you have the final "group" / "column" name.

Comment: it works!! thanks a lot for helping!! I created "unique_records" column to create the index, but it didnt work for me. Thanks a ton for helping out, do you have any resource or literature that can help me better understand what we did?

Comment: I've attempted to add an explanation to my answer if that helps. Let me know if you don't understand any specific parts and I can try improve it.

Comment: Thanks @jqurious, I ran the code for 150k respondents and 10 loops which would have resulted in 1.5 Million rows, but I got OOM error, any idea how to resolve that ? or run code in an efficient manner ?

Comment: I've added another possible approach using `.concat` instead of `.melt` + `.pivot` which should be much more efficient. Will the `_loopN` columns always have the same `N`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a type of [`.melt`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html#polars.DataFrame.melt):

```
(df
 .melt(
    id_vars = df.select(pl.exclude(r"^ht_\w+$")).columns, 
    variable_name = "age")
 .with_columns(
    pl.col("age").str.replace(r"^[^_]+_", ""))
)
```

```
shape: (18, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬─────┬───────┐
│ famid ┆ birth ┆ age ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ str ┆ f64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ one ┆ 2.8   │
│ 1     ┆ 2     ┆ one ┆ 2.9   │
│ 1     ┆ 3     ┆ one ┆ 2.2   │
│ 2     ┆ 1     ┆ one ┆ 2.0   │
│ …     ┆ …     ┆ …   ┆ …     │
│ 2     ┆ 3     ┆ two ┆ 2.4   │
│ 3     ┆ 1     ┆ two ┆ 3.3   │
│ 3     ┆ 2     ┆ two ┆ 3.4   │
│ 3     ┆ 3     ┆ two ┆ 2.9   │
└───────┴───────┴─────┴───────┘
```

---

**Update:** Showing how to `.melt` + `.pivot` as per updated example.

```
suffix = r"_loop\d+$"
id_vars = df.select(pl.exclude("^.+" + suffix)).columns

(df.melt(id_vars)
   .with_columns(pl.col("variable").str.replace(suffix, ""))
   .with_columns(row_nr = pl.first().cumcount().over("variable"))
   .pivot(index=id_vars + ["row_nr"], columns="variable", values="value", aggregate_function="first")
)
```

```
shape: (20, 6)
┌───────────┬────────┬────────────────┬────────┬──────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ Age_group ┆ Gender ┆ unique_records ┆ row_nr ┆ Familiarity          ┆ Affinity           │
│ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---            ┆ ---    ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                │
│ str       ┆ str    ┆ i64            ┆ i64    ┆ str                  ┆ str                │
╞═══════════╪════════╪════════════════╪════════╪══════════════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 36-50     ┆ Other  ┆ 0              ┆ 0      ┆ 0.5569650307413312   ┆ 0.9752962344272071 │
│ 19-35     ┆ Other  ┆ 1              ┆ 1      ┆ 0.8723228408633724   ┆ 0.9051378743187902 │
│ 19-35     ┆ Other  ┆ 2              ┆ 2      ┆ 0.010929392505575009 ┆ 0.7381748177290146 │
│ 36-50     ┆ Female ┆ 3              ┆ 3      ┆ 0.9782593916079607   ┆ 0.5099868864386063 │
│ …         ┆ …      ┆ …              ┆ …      ┆ …                    ┆ …                  │
│ 0-18      ┆ Female ┆ 6              ┆ 16     ┆ 0.6795089322714142   ┆ 0.3982539618169999 │
│ 19-35     ┆ Female ┆ 7              ┆ 17     ┆ 0.8168297900583801   ┆ 0.6198522863927297 │
│ 51-65     ┆ Female ┆ 8              ┆ 18     ┆ 0.46387232803532885  ┆ 0.9925845189718061 │
│ 51-65     ┆ Male   ┆ 9              ┆ 19     ┆ 0.20514774525608237  ┆ 0.9388295904692754 │
└───────────┴────────┴────────────────┴────────┴──────────────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

---

**Pivot explanation:**

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"variable": ["familiarity"] * 3 + ["affinity"] * 3, "value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
```

```
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────────────┬───────┐
│ variable    ┆ value │
│ ---         ┆ ---   │
│ str         ┆ i64   │
╞═════════════╪═══════╡
│ familiarity ┆ 1     │
│ familiarity ┆ 2     │
│ familiarity ┆ 3     │
│ affinity    ┆ 4     │
│ affinity    ┆ 5     │
│ affinity    ┆ 6     │
└─────────────┴───────┘
```

We use a [window function](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/window_functions.html?highlight=reshape#window-functions-) to generate "row ids" to be used in the pivot index.

This would be what you would use `.groupby` + `.cumcount` for in pandas.

```
>>> df.with_columns(row_nr = pl.first().cumcount().over("variable"))
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ variable    ┆ value ┆ row_nr │
│ ---         ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ str         ┆ i64   ┆ i64    │
╞═════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ familiarity ┆ 1     ┆ 0      │
│ familiarity ┆ 2     ┆ 1      │
│ familiarity ┆ 3     ┆ 2      │
│ affinity    ┆ 4     ┆ 0      │
│ affinity    ┆ 5     ┆ 1      │
│ affinity    ┆ 6     ┆ 2      │
└─────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```

```
(df.with_columns(row_nr = pl.first().cumcount().over("variable"))
   .pivot(index="row_nr", columns="variable", values="value", aggregate_function="first"))
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────┬─────────────┬──────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ familiarity ┆ affinity │
│ ---    ┆ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ i64    ┆ i64         ┆ i64      │
╞════════╪═════════════╪══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 1           ┆ 4        │
│ 1      ┆ 2           ┆ 5        │
│ 2      ┆ 3           ┆ 6        │
└────────┴─────────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks @jqurious, I tried to extend your example by adding 1 more variable which I want to stack, but it is not coming as expected. I have added the code in main question.